# Which is better: A laptop with intel core i7-7500U Processor OR intel core i7-8550U Processor

Tags: processor

I want to get a new laptop and I've been making lots of research. I've narrowed my two choices down to two laptops with their processor as intel core i7-7500U and intel core i7-8550U Processor. I'm not sure which is better but i'm assuming i7-8550U will be better because well, it's 8th Gen.

I have the differences between the both of them from intel's website compare. Kindly help me decide which is better. I will be using the laptop for programming, school work and casual gaming(fornite and overwatch).

```
                     core i7-7500U                              core i7-8550U
```

## Performance

```
# of cores                  2                                          4
# of threads                4                                          8
procesor base frequency     2.70GHz                                    1.80GHz
Max turbo frequency         3.50GHz                                    4.00GHz
Cache                       4MB smart cache                            8MB smart cache
Configurable TDP-up frequncy    2.90GHz                                2.00GHz
Configurable TDP-down           7.5W                                    10.0W
```

## Memory Specification

```
Memory Type          DDR4-2133,LPDDR3-1866,DDR3L-1600                 DDR4-2400,LPDDR3-2133
```

## Graphics Specification

```
Graphics Max Dynamic Frequency    1.05GHz                                 1.15GHz
Open GL support                   4.5                                  4.4
```

Comment: The [8550U has higher benchmarks](http://cpu.userbenchmark.com/Compare/Intel-Core-i7-7500U-vs-Intel-Core-i7-8550U/m171274vsm320742), also keep in mind that if you want to game I would highly advise the laptop you get is equipped with at least 8 gb of RAM, and a discrete graphics card. Many laptops shipping with the power savings series (U,T,S,etc.) Intel processors are mostly likely going to be budget laptops were corners are cut (iex. really slow hard drive). Chances are an Intel® UHD Graphics 620 isn't going to cut it for those games unless you set the settings really low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i7 8550u has twice the core count/threads, higher IPC, higher boost (which matters more as in intensive task it will turbo boost and not stay within stock clocks) and fair better in benchmark. Despite 8th gen being more power hungry, U chips should not eat up too many battery life. [9 hours of surfing web for HP X360 i5 7500u](https://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-Spectre-x360-13-w023dx-Convertible-Review.180538.0.html#toc-energy-management) and [around 8 hours for the 8th gen counterpart](https://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-Spectre-x360-13t-i7-8550U-FHD-SSD-Laptop-Review.289232.0.html#toc-energy-management)

Cinebench gets almost twice the points on

Multi core: [image: Cinebench multi]

And some substantial increase from single core: [image: Cinebench single]

Also, if you game on intel's HD graphics, be aware it's not the best choice and Fortnite isn't the lightest game to run, that is if you keep your expectations low and lower some settings/resolutions. Both processor run Intel HD 620 so the difference should not be far off. If you want, there are laptops with low powered MX130/150 graphics that isn't going to increase price a lot and does pretty well [Link to a review for HD 620](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SL2xceoiOLk)